# PrintWriter creates file but doesn't write

Tags: java, printwriter

I used the example code on a website somewhere and it looks like this:

```
package gdt.enlightening;

import notify.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class export {
    public static void Export(String path) {

        try {
            // Package.json
            File file = new File(path + "/package.json");

            FileWriter pw = new FileWriter(file);
            pw.write("test");
            pw.write("Hi!");

            pw.write("    \"id\": \"" + main.packageID + "\",\r\n");
            pw.write("    \"name\": \"test\",");

            notify.Notify.info("GDT Enlightening", "Finished exporting without errors.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

It creates the file but leaves it completely empty. I do not seem to figure out why. Do I need a "File" object?

I've tried different solutions found on here but it doesn't work. I've also played around with the printing method.

**EDIT:** Fixed by calling `pw.close()` at the end

Comment: Well, that should work (works fine for me). Are you sure you are looking at the right file ?

Comment: What is path? Please elaborate.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code. Perhaps you are looking in the wrong folder.

Comment: Perhaps your code is throwing an exception that you're not catching? Again, please elaborate. Post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Allright, it is under a try catch statement. I'll remove it.

Comment: I deleted the try catch, see my edit.

Comment: You did not close the FileWriter instance. Maybe the data are lost in a buffer.

Comment: Yes, that's it. By closing the FileWriter, you **flush** it.

Comment: Thank you :) Fixed it by closing 'pw'!

Comment: @user3902017 In the original question, you do specifically close the PrintWriter. What was the point of asking a question about completely fake code? (And who upvoted this garbage?)

Comment: I had tried with closing before, but that was with a PrintWriter. I changed because of another answer here, and closing that one worked.

Comment: 1+ to the question for the changes you made. For future reference, do you see how your minimal complete program helps us to identify your problem? It's a great way to help others to understand your problem and thus help you.

Comment: Thank god people like you are around, @HovercraftFullOfEels!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should add `pw.close()` to fix this problem.

Else that data will be lost in a buffer.

Comment: For the sake of education, **pw.flush()** will push all the data to disk and leave the file open for further writes.